# Get $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] variable value in Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I am new to python bottle framework and need to get $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] variable value specially. Pleas can some one explain how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it:

```
import request, route, run

@route('/user-agent')
def user_agent():
    return request.environ.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
run()
```